# Uncaught TypeError: p5 is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have some troubles to start my p5js, since I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: p5 is not a constructor`

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
export default {
    init() {
        //a P5 moire pattern.
        let s = (sk) => {
            let layers = [];

            // sk.translate(window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2);
            sk.setup = () =>{
                let gfx = sk.createGraphics(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                let gfx2;

                sk.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                sk.angleMode(sk.DEGREES);
                sk.imageMode(sk.CENTER);
                sk.translate(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
                sk.background(40);
                gfx.stroke(200);
                gfx.strokeWeight(3);
                gfx.line(0, 0, window.innerWidth, 0);
                for(let i=0; i<1000; i++){
                    gfx.point(Math.random() *window.innerWidth, Math.random() *window.innerHeight);
                }

                gfx2 = {...gfx};
                sk.image(gfx,0,0);
                sk.rotate(1);
                sk.image(gfx2,0,0);
            }

        }
        const P5 = new p5(s, document.getElementById('grid'));
    }
}
```

I my destination index.js the object gets just initialized as `myObject.init()`, `index.html` has a `div#grid` in it.
I can't see the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody with the same issue, I took for granted (following p5js docs and other resources about the library) that importing like `import * as p5 from 'p5'` was correct but it's a named export class so you need to `import p5 from 'p5'`. That worked.

Edit: words.